# How to adjust/re-train NLTK SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, tweets

I'm using `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` from NLTK to get a polarity of tweets about airline servies. There are many tweets about food quality and punctuality etc. With the code below I can obtain the polarity of a word.

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

sid.polarity_scores('delicious')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 1.0, 'compound': 0.5719}

sid.polarity_scores('delayed')
>>> {'neg': 1.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.2263}
```

However, there are many words that only returns "neutral".These words are frequently used for expressing the service quality of airlines, so I want to get a proper polarity somehow. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
sid.polarity_scores('tasty')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}

sid.polarity_scores('tasteless')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}

sid.polarity_scores('quick')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}

sid.polarity_scores('fast')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}

sid.polarity_scores('slow')
>>> {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe NLTK isnt the library to use. I prefer using TextBlob, here is an example code for you.

```
from textblob import TextBlob

words = ["good", "bad", "fast", "quick", "slow"]
for word in words:
    processedWord = TextBlob(word)
    print(processedWord.sentiment.polarity)
```

output:

```
0.7
-0.69
0.2
0.33
-0.30
```

i only got one problem when testing your words: `tasty`'s sentiment was neutral as well.

Comment: So the better question is what's the difference between the underlying algorithm in `nltk.sentiment.vader` and `TextBlob.sentiment.polarity`? **Always Always** understand what's the underlying model you're using.

Comment: thanks! For now i will use TextBlob. Meanwhile I will look for some other way to re-train pre-existing sentiment algorithm so that I can customise to my specific case.